# Data parse from JSON Response

Tags: java, android, json

I can't parse data from Response:

here is my snippet:

```
Response = '{"sys":"[{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Pirojpur Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Mathbaria Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Jhalokati Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Rajapur Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barguna Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Amtali Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barisal Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Banari Para Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Pirojpur Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Pirojpur Sadar Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barisal Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Muladi Upazila\"}]"}'; 
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray userdetails = json.getJSONArray("sys");
for (int i=0; i<userdetails.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject user = userdetails.getJSONObject(i);
     String division = user.getString("division");
     String district = user.getString("district");
     String upazilla = user.getString("upazilla");
}
```

I debug the code. Code stop when tried to check userdetails  length.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please post your logcat here also

Comment: use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: first remove \ from your resposne.!

Comment: typo in response...

Answer (score 1):

There should be no " in front of [{ nor after }]

This should work:

```
String response = "{\"sys\":[{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Pirojpur Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Mathbaria Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Jhalokati Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Rajapur Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barguna Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Amtali Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barisal Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Banari Para Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Pirojpur Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Pirojpur Sadar Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barisal Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Muladi Upazila\"}]}";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray userdetails = json.getJSONArray("sys");
        for (int i=0; i<userdetails.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject user = userdetails.getJSONObject(i);
            String division = user.getString("division");
            String district = user.getString("district");
            String upazilla = user.getString("upazilla");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below format. i.e:

```
String response = "{\"sys\":[{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Pirojpur Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Mathbaria Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Jhalokati Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Rajapur Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barguna Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Amtali Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barisal Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Banari Para Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Pirojpur Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Pirojpur Sadar Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barisal Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Muladi Upazila\"}]}";
```

And test [JSON format here](https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/) without "\"
& Your code of json parsing is right

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is:

```
{
    "sys": [{
        "division": "Barisal",
        "district": "Pirojpur Zila",
        "upazilla": "Mathbaria Upazila"
    }, {
        "division": "Barisal",
        "district": "Jhalokati Zila",
        "upazilla": "Rajapur Upazila"
    }, {
        "division": "Barisal",
        "district": "Barguna Zila",
        "upazilla": "Amtali Upazila"
    }, {
        "division": "Barisal",
        "district": "Barisal Zila",
        "upazilla": "Banari Para Upazila"
    }, {
        "division": "Barisal",
        "district": "Pirojpur Zila",
        "upazilla": "Pirojpur Sadar Upazila"
    }, {
        "division": "Barisal",
        "district": "Barisal Zila",
        "upazilla": "Muladi Upazila"
    }]
}
```

For automatic serialization and deserialization use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. This can be done in Gson in a very simple manner. Go to [jsonschematopojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and covert your json to pojo classes. the resultant pojo class for your json object is:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class YourJsonClass {

@SerializedName("sys")
@Expose
private List<Sy> sys = null;

public List<Sy> getSys() {
return sys;
}

public void setSys(List<Sy> sys) {
this.sys = sys;
}

public class Sy {

@SerializedName("division")
@Expose
private String division;
@SerializedName("district")
@Expose
private String district;
@SerializedName("upazilla")
@Expose
private String upazilla;

public String getDivision() {
return division;
}

public void setDivision(String division) {
this.division = division;
}

public String getDistrict() {
return district;
}

public void setDistrict(String district) {
this.district = district;
}

public String getUpazilla() {
return upazilla;
}

public void setUpazilla(String upazilla) {
this.upazilla = upazilla;
}
}
```

Now to access it, that's got simpler now,

```
String response = "{\"sys\":[{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Pirojpur Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Mathbaria Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Jhalokati Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Rajapur Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barguna Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Amtali Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barisal Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Banari Para Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Pirojpur Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Pirojpur Sadar Upazila\"},{\"division\":\"Barisal\",\"district\":\"Barisal Zila\",\"upazilla\":\"Muladi Upazila\"}]}";


Gson g1 = new Gson();
YourJsonClass response2 = g1.fromJson(response, YourJsonClass.class);
```

Now, you need to iterate the `response2` object as per your convenience.

```
for(int i=0; i < response2.getSys().size(); i++) {
   System.out.println(response2.getSys().get(i).getDivision());
   System.out.println(response2.getSys().get(i).getDistrict());
   System.out.println(response2.getSys().get(i).getUpazilla());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code :

```
String JSON_DATA =
    "{"
        + "  \"geodata\": ["
        + "    {"
        + "      \"id\": \"1\","
        + "      \"name\": \"Julie Sherman\","
        + "      \"gender\" : \"female\","
        + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.33774833333334\","
        + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.88670166666667\""
        + "    },"
        + "    {"
        + "      \"id\": \"2\","
        + "      \"name\": \"Johnny Depp\","
        + "      \"gender\" : \"male\","
        + "      \"latitude\" : \"37.336453\","
        + "      \"longitude\" : \"-121.884985\""
        + "    }"
        + "  ]"
        + "}";

JSONObject json;
JSONArray geodetails = null;
JSONObject user;
try {
  json = new JSONObject(JSON_DATA);
  geodetails = json.getJSONArray("geodata");
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

for (int i = 0; i < geodetails.length(); i++) {
  try {
    user = geodetails.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = user.getString("name");
    String gender = user.getString("gender");
    String latitude = user.getString("latitude");
    Log.d("Json response", " " + name+" "+gender+" "+latitude);

  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json response is not correct. There should not be any codes before JsonArray, response should be like this

```
{"sys":[{"division":"Barisal","district":"Pirojpur Zila","upazilla":"Mathbaria Upazila"},{"division":"Barisal","district":"Jhalokati Zila","upazilla":"Rajapur Upazila"},{"division":"Barisal","district":"Barguna Zila","upazilla":"Amtali Upazila"},{"division":"Barisal","district":"Barisal Zila","upazilla":"Banari Para Upazila"},{"division":"Barisal","district":"Pirojpur Zila","upazilla":"Pirojpur Sadar Upazila"},{"division":"Barisal","district":"Barisal Zila","upazilla":"Muladi Upazila"}]}
```